# Convert Float to int in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a pandas dataset in which i have to convert the float values to integer values in one particular column. I've tried various things but keep getting errors. Any ideas?

I've tried the following till now -

```
train['CoapplicantIncome']=train['CoapplicantIncome'].dropna().apply(np.int64)

train['CoapplicantIncome']=train['CoapplicantIncome'].apply(np.int64)

train['CoapplicantIncome']=train['CoapplicantIncome'].applymap(np.int64)

train['CoapplicantIncome']=train['CoapplicantIncome'].astype(int)
```

Comment: What is error here?

Comment: `df.astype({'col_name': 'int32'}).dtypes` will also work. Ref : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your first two and last lines should work, I tried it.

I can give you another way of doing it :

```
train['CoapplicantIncome'] = train['CoapplicantIncome'].map(int)
```

Please provide the error if this still doesn't solve it.

Comment: Glad it does ! Could you tag my answer as solving the post so that it gets closed ?